# Edits to plugin not taking effect

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I want to make some edits to a plugin that I've downloaded. I used the Plugin Editor, but the changes did not show up. I tried refreshing, logging out/back in, and deactivating/activating the plugin.

I gave up on that route and decided to:

- deactivate/delete the plugin via the admin page
- delete the plugin folder via FTP to make sure there were no remaining files
- make the desired edits to my local copy
- upload the folder to the site via FTP
- activate plugin

I verified that the new, edited file is up on the server, but the changes still do not show up.

I am guessing there is some sort of caching going on, but I don't know where to begin to clear it.

Other info that may be helpful:

- The URL of the page that I am trying to update is .../wp-admin/admin.php?page=dlm_addnew
- The plugin is Download Monitor and the file I updated is uploader.php
- I have no caching plugins and no wp-content/cache folder
- My site has cPanel, phpMyAdmin, etc.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does it say `You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See the Codex for more information.` underneath the text area?

Comment: Actually when I made the edits, it said something along the lines of "File edited successfully". But the changes didn't show up. That is why I decided to just delete the plugin, make the changes locally, and then upload it. Still doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to test for caching - make a plugin-breaking change (remove a `;` or something), upload it, and see what happens.  If your admin panel whitescreens, congratulations - you don't have caching.  If it doesn't, chances are your server is caching all php content with something APC.  Contact them and ask about caching.

Comment: So I tried to break it by removing a semicolon. Didn't work.

I contacted my host (hostpapa). They told me to refresh my browser cache (which I tried already). I also tried accessing the page in chrome incognito windows since it doesn't cache pages, and tried shift+f5 and ctrl+f5.

My host said that they had no caching on their end.

Comment: To confirm for sure, create a file in the root of your site called `info.php`, and put this in it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.  Then navigate to `mysite.com/info.php` and search for both APC and cache.  If there's still no caching, I wonder if the file you're editing is actually being called/used where you're expecting.

Comment: So I changed directions with this...  
I searched the entire plugin directory for a keyword of the code I was editing. I'm not sure why, but the plugin has code that isn't even used. I was editing a php file that apparently does nothing at all. haha. What a big waste of time. If anybody has this plugin (Download Monitor), the unused code is wp-content\plugins\download-monitor\uploader.php and the working code is wp-content\plugins\download-monitor\admin\add_new.php. I wonder if this is a bug that happened during an update, or if he meant to have redundant code for some reason.

Comment: It might be there as a fallback for older versions of WordPress.  I've run into a couple plugins that have 2-3 versions of a file that are WP version dependent.  Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wasn't aware that developers did that.